# XCode Server not sending email notifications to committers whether the build has passed or not

Tags: xcode

I have set a bot with post integration "Periodic Email report" but no reports are arriving at specified email address. I have the following set-up on my local macbook pro. I also have the macOS Server 5.4 running locally

[image: Mail Relay Setup]

[image: Bot Settings]

[image: XCode->Preferences->Server & Bots -> Mail]

please note that my command line "mail" command is sending mail fine - it is only that Bot's Post Integration step from which no emails are arriving  , please let me know how to troubleshoot and if there are any logs ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Command line mail is sending email. But Xcode build server is not. Can't find any error or warning logs. @akishnani did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that a working `mail` is not enough. You also need `mailq` to work. See https://gist.github.com/kany/c44c077881047ead8faa for more.

Especially this part if your `mailq` does not work as it did for me: https://gist.github.com/kany/c44c077881047ead8faa#gistcomment-2254978

Also, you can set up postfix to do proper mail forwarding if you prefer that avenue:

- https://blog.anupamsg.me/2012/02/14/enabling-postfix-for-outbound-relay-via-gmail-on-os-x-lion-11/

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49921025/2664531

(I can't mark this post as duplicate as this is my first post on AskDifferent)