# Xcode bot is not sending mail notifications

Tags: email, xcode

I've created a bot for Continuous Integration process using Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145). Under the Triggers section I did enable Email Notifications for Periodic Email Report. I'm expecting report after each integration just like mentioned in this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots.html). Even though bot is running perfectly fine, I'm not receiving an email with that report to my mail address (Ex. myname@officedomain.com and my office mail domain is based on outlook).

Is there any particular configuration that I need to do to receive these eMail notifications or is there any other thing that I'm missing?

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304848/xcode-server-not-sending-email-notifications-to-committers-whether-the-build-has). Also that question is not having a correct answer and the answer given is have saving email and password inside a configuration file. That's not a feasible solution in real world since I cannot ask my team to reveal their passwords to me.

Comment: Are you certain it’s not being sent? The problem may be that it’s not being received, which is different. When email is involved as the communication channel that is the first question that must be answered.  Did you check the spam filter?

Comment: @Tyson yes, I checked my spam folder as well. But haven't received any.